# Something similar to form2.cs or another page in winforms visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I just started using C# & Visual Studio for creating Windows Forms applications. I want to make another page or form for my application. For example, when someone will click on "show results" button in the form1.cs design, I want it to redirect them to another page or form2 that shows the results. From googling, I have only seen using "new Form2()" in the code and redesigning the whole new form again. Is there no alternative? if not then how big projects handle all these new forms designing and code?

Thanks!

Comment: There are absolutely ways to reuse UI components, either by just creating another instance of the *same* form, or creating reusable *usercontrols* that can be combined in different ways. But it is not very clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do, or what you have done so far.

Comment: To make it completely simple, assume I just created a new window form application, added two text boxes "email" & "password" & also a new button named "login" in the design and did a bit of coding to handle login stuff. Now, I want to redirect them to their dashboard page. How can I make a dashboard form or page? Form1 has two files, design & code. So I am expecting dashboard page (or Form2) to also have those files.

Comment: If you don't want to use multiple forms, then write each "screen" as a separate UserControl and then swap out the current UserControl in the main form via code somehow. You could make the UserControl fill up a container like a Panel for instance.  Another option might be to use a TabControl and switch tabs.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I would have tried using your approach but I just started using C# some days ago. So I am not familiar with the concepts of C# & .NET, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the following steps to solve your problem.

First, right-click on your project and choose “Add>New Item”. Create a new Form called dashboard.cs.
[image][image]

Second double-click on the button “login” in Form1 and add the code in Form1.cs:
[image]

```
private void Btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dashboard d = new dashboard();
        this.Hide();
        d.Show();
    }
```

Finally we can redirect to another page by click the login button.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly, what I wanted, thank you.